# Retrofit 2 call returns 500 as response

Tags: android, retrofit2

Call to web service using Retrofit2 is returning 500 internal server error. But the same web service, when called from postman and iOS device works perfectly. this is the call to the web service

```
@Multipart
@POST("domestic/post_job")
Call<PostJobResponse> postJob(@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> fields, @Part MultipartBody.Part part);`
```

this is the base url `http://jobshare.xtronlabs.com/job_share/index.php/`
and this is the function that calls the web service

```
public void post(String userid, String title, String description, int category_id, int sub_cat_id,
                 String skill_id, int postcode_id, String payment_type, double price, double hourly_rate,
                 double hours, java.io.File userfile, String deadline, boolean urgent,
                 boolean allow_comment, int bid_type) {

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(userid));
    params.put("title", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(title));
    params.put("description", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(description));
    params.put("category_id", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(category_id + ""));
    params.put("sub_cat_id", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(sub_cat_id + ""));
    params.put("skill_id", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(skill_id));
    params.put("postcode_id", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(postcode_id + ""));
    params.put("payment_type", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(payment_type));
    params.put("price", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(price == 0.0 ? " " : price + ""));
    params.put("hourly_rate", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(hourly_rate == 0.0 ? " " : hourly_rate + ""));
    params.put("hours", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(hours == 0.0 ? " " : hours + ""));
    params.put("deadline", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(deadline));
    params.put("urgent", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(urgent ? "1" : "0"));
    params.put("allow_comment", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(allow_comment ? "1" : "0"));
    params.put("bid_type", RequestHelper.getRequestBody(bid_type + ""));

    Call<PostJobResponse> call = mNetworkInterface.postJob(params, RequestHelper.multiPartBobyPart(userfile, "userfile"));
    call.enqueue(this);


}
```

Anybody know why it is behaving like this?

Comment: your response is empty.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. I got correct response in Postman

Comment: did you check if there is authentication required?

Comment: no there is no authentication. I send the data from postman without any authentication

Comment: i've already tried volley for multipart request in another project and it didn't work and so i switched to Retrofit

Comment: can you post your response as it here?

Comment: All other web services in the same domain are working in Retrofit

Comment: The correct one? or do you want the response in android device

Comment: both can be good if you can give

Comment: You should cross check the param's value. That might creating the issue for the server to produce the response!

Comment: `{
  "success": "Job added successfully"
}`
This is response in postman

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error http://jobshare.xtronlabs.com/job_share/index.php/domestic/post_job (1164ms)`

Comment: @android_griezmann i copied all the params from postman as a last resort. but it didn't work

Comment: check some other url with your same android function. 500 means, definitely will be in server side. you tell to your web service provider to make it cross check. because, some times post man will respond incorrectly.

Comment: postman is responding correctly and it is showing the correct response. Error occurs when called from android using retrofit2

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this way

```
@Multipart
@POST("domestic/post_job")
Call<PostJobResponse> postJob(@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> fields, @Part("userfile\"; filename=\"test.png\" ") RequestBody fbody);
```

and create call object like this way

```
File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), userfile);
Call<PostJobResponse> call = mNetworkInterface.postJob(params, fbody);
```